# Combination of two JS codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to validate a Polish zip code field which should be in 11-111 format

I have a little problem with combining two JS codes.

One of the codes is responsible for entering only numbers in the  field

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')
```

This code is for inserting a "-" after the second number.

```
if(this.value.length==2 && this.value.indexOf('-')==-1) this.value+='-';
```

I want to add the code in "oninput".

```
<input inputmode="numeric" oninput=""/>
```

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble combining both codes. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question. See [ask]. I suggest you ask how to accomplish your goal rather than how to mash two lines of code together (which may not be appropriate in general).

Comment: Why aren't you using a number input?

Comment: @mplungjan To the zip code field. In Poland it is used in the 11-111 format. And this is the data I want to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow numbers and hyphens and add a hyphen in the 3rd position

You can add to it if you want to make sure the hyphen is the 3rd character and there are only 7 characters

Your example was testing decimal points etc

```js
document.getElementById("zip").addEventListener("input", function() {
  let val = this.value;
  if (val.length == 2 && val.indexOf('-') !== 2) val += '-';
  val = val.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '');
  this.value = val;
})
```

```html
<input inputmode="numeric" id="zip">
```